# patch-ahead condition not working for turtle to stop

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to stop moving turtle on `patch-ahead 1 condition`, that is the turtle should stop if it finds another turtle with the specific property such as stationary on its next adjacent patch, 
actually, I want to stop turtles adjacent to each other when reaching to stationary turtles.

```
ifelse (not any? (turtles-on patch-ahead 1) with [stationary? = true]) [
  fd 0.1
  rt random 360
] [
  set stationary? true
  stop
]
```

Actually, I am using patch-ahead 1 condition for stopping my turtles in drawing imported by using "`import-pcolors`" command.

drawing or shape (such as star-fish) is aligned on the center of the world's patches and 4 turtles(seeds) are placed near the center of the origin within shape drawing remained stationary until the end, all other turtles are placed randomly and also moves randomly in the world with `stationary? = false`.

The goal is to completely fill the shape(drawing) without leaving any patch empty in the drawing, by moving the turtles randomly and stop when approaches to next stationary turtle and become `stationary? = true`, and reference for all other remaining non-stationary turtles.

here is what I have tried so far,

```
    to setup
      import-pcolors "starnew.png" ; image imported in the world on patches for turtles to interact

      create-robots num-of-robots
        [
          set seed? false
          set stationary? false
        set shape "circle 2"  
        setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
      ]

      ask turtles
      [
        if who = 0 ; similarly for who = 1 (setxy = 0 1 ), who = 2 (setxy = 1 0 ), who = 3 (setxy = 0 -1 ),  having loaction near centre origin 
        [
          setxy  0 0
          set seed? true
          set stationary? true
          set localized? true
          ]
      ]   
    end
    to go
ask robots with [stationary? != true]
  [

    ifelse pcolor = white   ;; out-shape
      [
        wall
        fd 0.1
        rt random 30
        lt random 30
      ]
      [                     ;; In-shape
        set pos-inside? true
        ifelse ( not any? (robots-on patch-ahead 1 ) with [stationary? = true or seed? = true]   )
        [
          fd 0.1
          rt random 30
          lt random 30
        ]
        [
          set pos-inside? true
          set stationary? true
          set localized? true
          stop
        ]
      ]
  ]
  end
```

the desired behavior I want to achieve is shown in the picture below.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say for sure without looking at your setup code (see the [MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) but I suspect that your turtles are all starting out with `stationary?` equal to `false` and there are no turtles starting out with `stationary` set to true (for the wandering turtles to react to. When I run your code with a few stationary turtles, it does work as far as I can tell. Try this slightly modified version and see if that gets closer to what you're after:

```
turtles-own [ stationary? ]

to setup 
  ca
  crt 50 [
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set stationary? false
  ]
  ask n-of 15 turtles [
    set stationary? true
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles with [ stationary? = false ] [
    ifelse (not any? (turtles-on patch-ahead 1) with [stationary? = true]) [
      fd 0.1
      rt random 360
    ] [
      print "Found a stationary turtle. I'll be stationary too."
      set stationary? true
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Luke C, thanks for your kind help.
you got it right .

Comment: but let me clarify my scenario.